# Adding distant fog with the sun lamp

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I've been using a sun lamp to light an outdoor environment in the Eevee engine. I've got a HDRI but only as an image (no lighting data) because I didn't enjoy how it lit up the environment and I couldn't tweak it to find a way I like. I'm using the lamp to create lighting I'm more or less happy with.
[image: Blender Mesa with no fog]

Problem is, I'm trying to create fog so that the background will fade away, instead of coming to a sudden halt. But as I have read, the sun lamp doesn't work with volumetric lighting, and volumetrics seems to be the only way I can find to create fog.

Is there another alternative to creating fog that works with the sun lamp? I'm looking to stick with the Eevee engine, as the task I am working on requires an environment suited for real time.

Comment: Have you tried the mist pass in compositing?

Comment: @Bruno I guess that works, thanks! I don't suppose there's any way to limit it vertically? For example, if I wanted some fog on the lower part of the screen to fade out with nothing on top.

Comment: you could multiply the mist pass  with a vertical gradient...